Building class library project, trim down dependency assembly
I am building a .NET 4.6 class library. In it, I have a nuget package which is 50 mb in 1 assembly. Is there any build tool that enables me to trim down the 50 mb assembly to remove code that is not used by my own library? Or one that allows me to break down the 50 mb assembly into chunks of 15 mb?
